# Clarification on rails collection routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

**routes.rb**

```
resources :home do
 get 'download', :on => :collection
end
```

**rake routes**

```
download_home_index GET    /home/download(.:format)     home#download
home_index GET             /home(.:format)              home#index
....
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def index
end
```

When i go to http://localhost:3000/home/download, it works even though there is no "download" action in the home_controller. I am confused why even without the action, it doesn't complain missing action.

I was curious so I added `resources :homes` to routes.rb and `rake routes` gave me the following:

```
homes GET    /homes(.:format)             homes#index
```

In comparison, it is not homes_index whereas it was home_index before. Is there some rails magic going on? Appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, if you have a view for the action, you don't strictly need the action defined (but you really should).

For the second question, you defined `resources :homes` vs `resources :home`, hence the generated routes are different. `resources :home` is incorrect.